# How do I let a div spill text into another div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am creating an application in React using react-bootstrap. I've stumbled into a problem I can't find the solution to. I want to have the name of the person (`person.name`-div) spill onto the image.

I've tried googling, finding multiple suggestions using `white-space: nowrap`, `overflow-wrap: normal`, `word-wrap: normal` and `hyphens: manual`, but none of these work in the below example.

I've made the following [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/hammerbak/pen/PoYjeGq), which illustrates the problem in the attached screenshot. The CodePen is not in react, but regular bootstrap, as I don't expect that this is a react specific issue, but rather a bootstrap/html issue.

```css
.profile-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div p.person-name {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div .person-title {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div .person-contact {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.image-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class='container profile-item'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-12 col-sm-12'>
      <div class='profile-info'>
        <div class='info-div'>
          <p class='person-name'>Mr. Very Cool Super Cool Mega Cool</p>
          <p class='person-title'>Circus Clown</p>
          <p class='person-contact'>T: +45 12345678</p>
          <p class='person-contact'>E: mrcool@circusclown.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class='image-div'>
          <img class='person-image' src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x191' alt='profile picture' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-12 col-sm-12'>
      <div className='profile-content'>
        <p className='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent fermentum sapien a erat aliquet malesuada. Donec fringilla lacus maximus lobortis convallis. Nam elementum quam non nulla imperdiet gravida at quis metus. Pellentesque sagittis
          tincidunt libero eget interdum. Suspendisse eleifend dui in nisi laoreet convallis. Vestibulum blandit luctus nunc, in vehicula neque condimentum eget. Aenean congue velit vitae tristique dapibus. Aliquam malesuada pretium posuere. Nulla consequat
          consequat ante, in mattis nunc posuere vitae. Maecenas aliquet augue luctus, porta erat in, dignissim libero. Donec laoreet, lectus id rutrum hendrerit, est ex iaculis lacus, sit amet consequat metus nunc ac ligula. Duis sodales auctor eros
          a vestibulum. Cras in risus sed metus fermentum mattis porttitor quis enim. In id pretium lorem. Proin suscipit vitae dui consequat interdum. Proin vitae maximus purus. Phasellus cursus, tellus sit amet luctus fermentum, nisi nisi lacinia dui,
          id blandit nisi nisl et turpis. Sed ultrices luctus libero a porttitor. Mauris convallis, sapien in rutrum sodales, augue lorem tempus dolor, vel mollis est velit in turpis. Donec a justo consectetur, dictum dolor nec, tristique elit. Etiam
          convallis sem id porttitor facilisis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Letting person.name spill over image]

I want to have the `person.name`-div spill over the image. Ideally a regular name would not have the length I've tried to test it with. Wrapping would not be a problem as long as the text spills onto the image and wraps at the width of the "page".

Comment: Hi; we need to see a [mre] of your code in the question itself -- a screenshot of what it looks like is inadequate.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what you want so I'm not adding this as an answer. Add `style="z-index: 1"` to `person-name` and add `style="position: absolute; right:0; z-index: 0;"` to `image-div`. If that works you can adjust your css classes accordingly

Comment: @TylerH. Check the codepen out. It does have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Dumisani. I'll try that out. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeliax Debugging questions must include the code *in the question itself* - a link to a CodePen/JSFiddle, like a screenshot, is inadequate on its own. This is to prevent your question from losing all its value when CodePen goes down or you change the code at that URL (or make it private), or the link dies. My 'minimal reproducible example' link in my first comment explains that requirement in detail, if you haven't read it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. I set the `div.image-div` to position absolute with a `z-index` of 1. Then took the `info-div` and gave it a higher z-index.

```css
.profile-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div p.person-name {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div .person-title {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.info-div .person-contact {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.profile-item div.profile-info div.image-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container profile-item'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-12 col-sm-12'>
      <div class='profile-info'>
        <div class='info-div'>
          <p class='person-name'>Mr. Very Cool Super Cool Mega Cool</p>
          <p class='person-title'>Circus Clown</p>
          <p class='person-contact'>T: +45 12345678</p>
          <p class='person-contact'>E: mrcool@circusclown.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class='image-div'>
          <img class='person-image' src='https://via.placeholder.com/140x191' alt='profile picture' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-12 col-sm-12'>
      <div className='profile-content'>
        <p className='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent fermentum sapien a erat aliquet malesuada. Donec fringilla lacus maximus lobortis convallis. Nam elementum quam non nulla imperdiet gravida at quis metus. Pellentesque sagittis
          tincidunt libero eget interdum. Suspendisse eleifend dui in nisi laoreet convallis. Vestibulum blandit luctus nunc, in vehicula neque condimentum eget. Aenean congue velit vitae tristique dapibus. Aliquam malesuada pretium posuere. Nulla consequat
          consequat ante, in mattis nunc posuere vitae. Maecenas aliquet augue luctus, porta erat in, dignissim libero. Donec laoreet, lectus id rutrum hendrerit, est ex iaculis lacus, sit amet consequat metus nunc ac ligula. Duis sodales auctor eros
          a vestibulum. Cras in risus sed metus fermentum mattis porttitor quis enim. In id pretium lorem. Proin suscipit vitae dui consequat interdum. Proin vitae maximus purus. Phasellus cursus, tellus sit amet luctus fermentum, nisi nisi lacinia dui,
          id blandit nisi nisl et turpis. Sed ultrices luctus libero a porttitor. Mauris convallis, sapien in rutrum sodales, augue lorem tempus dolor, vel mollis est velit in turpis. Donec a justo consectetur, dictum dolor nec, tristique elit. Etiam
          convallis sem id porttitor facilisis.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```